# PHP $_POST array empty with Apache and PHP 7.4 (CLI/CGI)

Tags: php, apache, curl, post

I am trying to test if a php script to access POST parameters is working but am running into trouble. Accessing the $_POST array returns a zero value (see below).

First I run curl in bash as:

```
curl -v -X POST http://example.com/test.php -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'name=bob&id=5'
```

The test.php script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/php-cgi
<?php
errort_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] . "\n';
echo $_POST['name'] . "\n";
echo var_dump($_POST);
```

The output from curl is then:

```
*  Trying 12.34.567.89:80
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 12.34.567.89 (12.34.567.89) port 80 (#0)
> POST /test.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: 12.34.567.89
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 16
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 16 out of 16 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 23 Jul 2023 12:34:56 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Unix)
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
POST

Notice: Undefined index: name in /test.php on line 11

array(0) {
}
* transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
* closing connection 0
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

I replicated the issue locally. After trimming down my apache .config file, the issue still remains. The config file is

```
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
    User daemon
    Group daemon
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin you@example.com

ServerName www.example.com:80

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/srv/apache/htdocs"

<Directory "/srv/apache/htdocs">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/srv/apache/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>


<Directory "/srv/apache/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None    
    Options None 
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The access log shows

```
12.34.567.89 - - [23/Jul/2023:17:35:47 +0000] "POST /cgi-bin/test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 846
```

The error log shows

```
[Sun Jul 23 17:35:47.188923 2023] [core:error] [pid 3608972:tid 140226028996352] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 12.34.567.89:34618] AH00574: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed
```

I am running PHP as a CGI compiler in Apache. The binary information is

```
/usr/bin/php --version
PHP 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.18 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2023 12:43:23) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0 copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPache v7.4.3-4ubuntu2.18, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

It seems to me that the request is reaching the right end point but that the body is not reaching there. Based on this I'm thinking something in my apache configuration may not be passing on the information (maybe `mod_rewrite`?).

I have tried changing the `'Content-Type'` to `'form-data'` and changing the  `'-d'` option value to .json `'{"name":"bob","id":5}'` but this gave the same result as above.

I'm running Apache on Linux. I read online it could be Apache's mod_rewrite causing issues, so I tried accessing the .php script directly, but this gave the same output as above.

This is my first time handling POST requests and I'm not sure where the issue is. Any help in pointing to a solution would be appreciated. An explanation of why would also be helpful.

## EDIT

I notice the `error_log` above features `[client 12.34.567.89:52546]` and I'm not sure the port `52546` should be involved. I've tried explicitly requesting on port 80 multiple times - each time the port number in `[client ip:port]` changes. Does anyone know what this may be, or if it could be the issue ?

Comment: Try adding `-H 'Content-Length: 15'`, and see what you get. I seem to remember having an issue like this in the past, where PHP wouldn't parse my request without knowing the  content length needed.

Comment: Thankyou for the comment. I tried but unfortunately this gave the same zero result as above.

Comment: OK, I'll ask maybe a dumb question and hope I'm wrong.  Are you expecting the PHP to automatically display in your browser the request from your curl post? If so, it doesn't work that way since PHP is a server side language.  You'll need to save the results in some way and then display that in your browser.

Comment: I'm only expecting curl to display results in the bash terminal. I'm not using a browser in the testing I'm doing here. I think that answers the question ?

Comment: It does answer the question.  I would next try turning on error reporting.... `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I added error reporting, which says the index key doesn't exist - see the edit.

Comment: @user10709800: The apache configuration is maybe what you're currently in, but the logging is often more interesting. Something is not working, better find something as well in the logs.

Comment: how do you have error on line 11 for this script that is only 3 lines? ok. few enters (break lines), but still... it does not look nice.

Comment: The full script sets error reporting on and has commented out lines.

Comment: try with clean script (if possible). hoisting/early binding/whatever... is not the easiest to troubleshoot. you are troubleshooting orange problem with apples :)

Comment: could it be the issue? no. see %a in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errorlogformat and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking). I don't see anything in the apache configuraiton regarding how you integrate PHP with it, which PHP SAPI are you using? And why didn't you share that part with the configuration (just asking)?

Comment: PHP is run as a CGI script so no Apache configuration takes place. Instead, I include the path to the server PHP compiler at the scripts beginning - #!/usr/bin/php.

Comment: CGI, Are you sure? Add `/usr/bin/php --version` information of the CGI binary to your question (full command-line and it's output).

Comment: @user10709800: There you have it, you're not using the PHP CGI binary. See the output, it is CLI. Use a different SAPI, because CGI: https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.php / https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.commandline.php -- Perhaps as your setup is that special, add the apache version to your question as well.

Comment: Great. Thankyou for pointing this out. I can run `php-cgi test.php` fine in bash but via http it does not work. I'm using `#!/usr/bin/php-cgi` as the first line. The error log gives `malformed header from script 'test.php': Bad Header: <b>Security Alert!</b> The PHP` . Any ideas ?

Comment: @user10709800: It is ages ago when I last used PHP-CGI, I early migrated to FCGI, even before it was available in PHP itself as my systemadmin took care. So ... no. But you can search for that. And probably you want, again, add those clarifications to your question by [edit]ing it.

Answer (score 1):

Some good and some bad news. First of all testing a POST request with curl on the command line is a good approach, however know it well enough so you don't look for problems there and not on the server-side.

curl(1) sends POST requests with `-d 'name=bob&id=5'` and the URL alone. You don't have to try `-X ...` or `-H ...`. This is also what you noticed, this didn't make any difference. Keep it more simple so that you don't need to guess there:

```
curl -d 'name=bob&id=5' http://example.com/test.php
```

*(you could also place the URL in front, it's just a habit of mine I have it after the `-...` options and their arguments as the URL is a positional parameter [you can add more than one])*

The bad news probably is that you're testing against the wrong server.

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
echo $_POST['name'];
```

can never generate

```
POST
array(0) {}
```

and even if it is actually similar but with a var_dump(), the curl command line you have in question does work.

Now here is the benefit of using curl(1) on the command line for testing these things: You can easily *inspect* what is going on, at least from the client side. The switch is `-v` and if you add it to the mix you will see details about the connection (`*`), data being send to the server `>` and also data being recieved `<` - next to the response itself.

Example:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:8080/ -d 'name=bob&id=5'
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 13
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Host: localhost:8080
< Date: Sat, 22 Jul 2023 11:35:53 GMT
< Connection: close
< X-Powered-By: PHP/8.2.8
< Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
POST
bob
array(0) {
}
* Closing connection 0
```

The `index.php` file used in this example:

```php
<?php

echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], "\n";
echo $_POST['name'], "\n";
var_dump($_POST);
```

And how the PHP development server was started in the same directory as index.php:

```
$ php8.2 -n -S localhost:8080
[Sat Jul 22 13:35:29 2023] PHP 8.2.8 Development Server (http://localhost:8080) started
[Sat Jul 22 13:35:53 2023] 127.0.0.1:35642 Accepted
[Sat Jul 22 13:35:53 2023] 127.0.0.1:35642 [200]: POST /
[Sat Jul 22 13:35:53 2023] 127.0.0.1:35642 Closing
```

*(open it in a different terminal, then you can track both curl and PHP)*

The development webserver can help you to check if your test-procedure works, so you can also exclude already some parts.

But this is not a requirement, I just did it this way to reproduce your issue (and failed ;)).

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed answer and pointing out the -v tag. I followed your approach and added the result in the EDIT above.